# Issue launching android emulator from windows command line

Tags: android-studio

AVD launches fine from Android Studio, and when I run "emulator -list-avds" from commands line, I get "Nexus6".....however when I run "emulator -avd Nexus6", I get "PANIC: "Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU"

Has anyone seen this issues before?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - I just downgraded the API for the AVD from 27 to 23....now its working.
Appears AVDM had an issue with using most recent API (27), as under the "target" field it was showing [Android null] (as opposed to e.g. [Android 6.0]